# I suddenly don't see launcher and I can't even start terminal

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, 13.10, launcher

I've been using Ubuntu 13.10 for a year now, and everything worked just fine. Suddenly, after turning my lap top on, I didn't see the launcher, and I can't find the way to start the terminal. Thanks to right-click and open with... option, I can see all the installed programs and use them, but there is no terminal. 
How could I fix it?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Alt T  should pop up a terminal, or you could switch to a virtual term with Ctrl-Alt-F2. .  What you are seeing may possibly be fixed by renaming the .config file in your home directory (to force a new one to be made).  I had a second blank desktop blocking my original after an update, and the symptoms were similar to yours.  If you have things in .config you want, you can copy them from the old one to the new one.